# ion-select multiple select with popover interface, disable last option on change if it's only one remaining

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, capacitor, ionic6

Requirement

1. there should be an ion select with multiple selection
2. default all should be selected
3. when interacting with it, if there is one selected left, that option should get disabled.
4. and if in next action, other options are getting selected, disabled option should get enabled again.

Simple agenda is to not let user deselect all of them, at least one should remain selected (last remaining).

I have tried different approaches, with popover, actionsheet and alert, for all of three it's has the behaviour as, Ion-select option gets disable property check reflected, but the native code for popover that is getting generated with ion-popover is not reflecting same on ion-items with checkbox on popover.

It gets disable only once the popover is dismissed and opened again. in this case as well, if user starts selecting other, the other option should get enabled again as we have multiple choices now, (that logic is not added in snippet below, i.e once disabled next step is to enable it on other options selection).

HTML:

```
<ion-col
     size="auto"
     *ngIf="floorOptions.length">
    <ion-select
         class="filter-drop"
         interface="popover"
         [multiple]="true"
         [ngModel]="floorsSelected"
         (ionChange)="filterByFloor($event)"
         [selectedText]="selectedTextFloor">
              <ion-select-option
                  *ngFor="let op of floorOptions"
                  [value]="op.floorID">
                       {{op.floorName}}
                  </ion-select-option>
     </ion-select>
</ion-col>
```

TS:

```
MIN_FILTER_OPTIONS_LENGTH:number = 1;// atleast one option to remain selected.
floorOptions = 
[
    {
        "floorID": "1",
        "floorName": "Floor 1",
        "isOn": true
    },
    {
        "floorID": "2",
        "floorName": "Floor 2",
        "isOn": true
    },
    {
        "floorID": "3",
        "floorName": "Floor 3",
        "isOn": true
    },
    {
        "floorID": "4",
        "floorName": "Floor 4",
        "isOn": true
    },
    {
        "floorID": "5",
        "floorName": "Floor 5",
        "isOn": true
    }
];
floorsSelected = [];
lastFloor: boolean = false;
invalidSelectClass = false;
selectedTextFloor = 'All floors';

  filterByFloor(floorChangedEvent) {
    this.floorsSelected = floorChangedEvent.detail.value;
    this.floorOptions.map((floor) => {
      floor.isOn = this.floorsSelected.indexOf(floor.floorID) != -1;
    });
    this.selectedTextFloor = this.floorsSelected.length === this.floorOptions.length ? 'All floors': '';
    this.lastFloor = this.floorsSelected.length == MIN_FILTER_OPTIONS_LENGTH;
    console.log(this.lastFloor);
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    if (!this.floorsSelected.length) {
      this.invalidSelectClass = true;
      this.uiUtilityService.showToast({ message: 'Please select atleast one floor to see results.' });
      return;
    }
    // this.applyFilters(); // function to filter records based on selection
  }
```

[image: Ion-select Popover with multi- select option by default all selected]

Ionic Info

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.3 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.2.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 14.2.1
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 14.2.1
   @angular/cli                  : 14.2.1
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 4.1.0
   @capacitor/android : not installed
   @capacitor/core    : 4.1.0
   @capacitor/ios     : not installed

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : 0.15.4
   native-run (update available: 1.7.1) : 1.6.0

System:

   NodeJS : v16.14.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 8.5.0
   OS     : macOS
```

Comment: 建議監聽 ionChange 事件，並使用一個變數去控制提交的按鈕 disable

Comment: @Lonyui It is not about disabling the submit button, it is disable the ion-select-option itself when it's the only one checked and left.

Comment: 我想這是可以實現的，監聽 ionchange 事件，把邏輯寫到裡面。初始全選就寫道 init 裏面。 以下有 disabled 的寫法參考 https://codepen.io/brandyscarney/pen/Baybgby 希望有幫助